# How to prevent homemade butter from melting/separating under hot conditions

Tags: substitutions, storage-method, chocolate, butter, food-processing

Please, I'm making homemade butter that will be kept and served at an outdoor event. What process/additive/ingredient can I add to preparation that will prevent the butter from separating or melting in the outdoor heat(or under direct sunlight). Thanks.

Comment: Bought butter will do this too, though possibly be a bit more forgiving. The only solution is to keep it cool.

Answer (score 1):

You can't.

fat is fat and will melt under hot conditions.

Keep it cool, put it over some ice.

Comment: Well, there's sort of a caveat, the structure of butter is more complicated than just fat - notably, more fat crystals and less fat globules and free fat means firmer butter, and this is affected by the post-churning stages of buttermaking. It's probably difficult for the OP to do *too* much in that regard, though, and it can only get so firm anyway. A hot sunny day will probably always melt it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a process that will change the melting point.

Some materials you can heat to a certain temperature then cool to effect physical properties but butter is not one.

You might be able to hydrogenate.  It works with margarine but not sure it will work with butter.  I don't think butter has double bonds to break.  If it worked with butter it seems like we would see it in the market.

If you add something it is not really butter any more.  But you could add edible paraffin wax. I just don't think it would taste very good.

Could you put out small dishes at a time with thick ceramic walls to hold cold?

Comment: Thanks, I'll try out the edible paraffin wax. If that doesn't work, I'll use ice to keep it cool and a butter crock when serving.